# How to get clean URLs on AWS Cloudfront (S3)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm hosting my static website on AWS S3, with Cloudfront as a CDN, and I'm wondering how I can get clean URLs working.

I currently have to go to `example.com/about.html` to get the about page. I'd prefer `example.com/about` as well as across all my other pages. Also, I kind of have to do this because my canonical URLs have been set with meta tags and search engines, and it's gonna be a bit much to go changing them.

Is there a setting in Cloudfront that I'm non seeing?

### Updates

There are two options I've explored, one detailed by Matt below.

First is trimming `.html` off the file before uploading to S3 and then editing the Content Header in the http for that file. This might work beautifully, but I can't figure out how to edit content headers from the command line, where I'm writing my "push website update" bash script.

Second is detailled by Matt below and leverages S3's feature that recognizes root default files, usually index.html. Might be a great approach, but it makes my local testing challenging, and it leaves a trailing slash on the URLs which doesn't work for me.

Comment: I ended up writing a build script that copies all the html files without the '.html' at the end of the file names, and then pushing them to the s3 bucket with content-type html specified in the push command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **AWS Lamda@Edge**. It solves this completely.

First, create an AWS Lambda function and then attach your CloudFront as a trigger.

In the code section of this AWS Lamda page, add the snippet in the repository below.

https://github.com/CloudUnder/lambda-edge-nice-urls/blob/master/lambdaRewrite.js

**Note the options in the readme section of the repo**

Answer (score 4):

When you host your website in S3 (and by extension CloudFront), you can configure S3 to have a "default" file to load when a directory is requested. This is called the "index document".

For example, you can configure S3 to load `index.html` as the default file. This way, if the request was for `example.com/abc/`, then it would load `abc/index.html`.

When you do this, if they requested `example.com/abc/123.html`, then it will serve up `abc/123.html`. So the default file only applies when a folder is requested.

To address your request for `example.com/about/`, you could configure your bucket with a default file of `index.html`, and put `about/index.html` in your bucket.

More information can be found in Amazon's documentation: [Index Document Support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html).

Comment: This is nice to know : )

Comment: Hi @Costa, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks, John! This doesn't answer my question. Not sure how to clarify my question further.

Comment: @Costa, why doesn't this answer your question? You asked how to get your page to be `example.com/about` instead of `example.com/about.html`, and I explained how to do that. What else were you looking for?

Comment: It's a valid workaround, but it has costs, like rearranging my whole working directory. There's a trailing slash in your example, also, which isn't how my canonical URLs are listed currently in my site. Definitely helpful to know this option exists though, thank you!

Comment: I think moreover that this method does not work as expected, since Cloudfront's default root is only for the site root, not subdirectories. Confer:https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

Comment: I tried this with my site that has a S3 + Cloudfront and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome **ugly urls** by using a custom origin, when your S3 bucket is configured as a website endpoint, with your Cloudfront distribution. The downside is that you can't configure Cloudfront to use HTTPS to communicate between Cloudfront and your origin. You can still use HTTPS, just not end-to-end encryption.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and Matt's method above worked with me. But it seems every page you want to hide should be named "index.html" and then insert it in a folder in S3 with the name you want to be shown in your URL or Website - like /about, /gallery, etc...

Then in your HTML code of each index.html page, refer to other pages by writing the folder path only, with either "/about", or "/about/". But as the AWS [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html) says you have to always stick with one way of writing trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambda as a reverse proxy to your website.

In API Gateway you need to create a "proxy resource" with resource path = "{proxy+}"

Then, create a Lambda function to route the requests:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const myBucket = 'myBucket';

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    var responseBody = "";

    if (event.path=="/") {
        responseBody = "<h1>My Landing Page</h1>";
        responseBody += "<a href='/about'>link to about page</a>";
        return buildResponse(200, responseBody);
    }

    if (event.path == "/about") {

        var params = { 
            Bucket: myBucket,
            Key: 'path/to/about.html',
        };

        const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

        return buildResponse(200, data.Body.toString('utf-8'));
    }

    return buildResponse(404, 'Page Not Found');

};


function buildResponse(statusCode, responseBody) {

    var response = {
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "statusCode": statusCode,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type" : "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        },
        "body": responseBody,
    };

    return response;
}
```

Then you can create a CloudFront distribution for your API Gateway, using your custom domain.

For more details check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913763/2444386

Comment: I ended up writing a build script that copies all the html files without the '.html' at the end of the file names, and then pushing them to the s3 bucket with content-type html specified in the push command.