# Avoid CORS with AWS Cloudfront, and clean SPA urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have a single-page app that lives in S3, fronted by Cloudfront. There's also a backend that the SPA talks to via AJAX requests. I'm trying to both:

1. have clean URLs (a la https://keita.blog/2015/11/24/hosting-a-single-page-app-on-s3-with-proper-urls/), by asking cloudfront to rewrite 403 and 404 errors into 200s that produce the index page, *and*
2. avoid CORS issues by adding a cloudfront behavior to proxy `/api/*` to the server (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42883221/1586229).

Is it possible to accomplish both of these? The problem is that cloudfront will change even 403s and 404s that come from the api into `200 index.html` responses.

If this can't be done, can you recommend another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior can be accomplished with Lambda@Edge. Here's the plan:

Create a Lambda function that will be triggered on Origin Request (see diagram for where in the lifecycle that lands). Be sure to create it in `us-east-1`, as that's the only region where Lambdas to be used in Lambda@Edge can be defined.

[image: Cloudfront possible locations for a Lambda@Edge function]

The function has the following job: rewrite requests to paths like `/login`, `/profile`, `/anything_other_than_assets` into `/index.html`. For me, I was able to make the rule:

> Something is an asset if it has an extension. Otherwise, it's a path

Hopefully, you can do the same, or similar. Here's how my function body looked (I used node 8)

```
const path = require('path')

exports.handler = (evt, ctx, cb) => {
    const {request} = evt.Records[0].cf

    if (!path.extname(request.uri)) {
        request.uri = '/index.html'
    }

    cb(null, request)
}
```

Make sure you "Publish a new version", and then copy the arn (found at the top of the page)

[image: where to copy the ARN of your new lambda function]

paste it in the "Lambda function associations" section of your S3 Origin's Behavior.

[image: Where to paste the ARN of your lambda function]

Because Lambda@Edge function associates are scoped to the Origin level, this redirect behavior won't affect your `/api/*` behavior.

Make sure to remove the custom error handlers. You won't need them anymore for your S3 behavior, and you don't want them for your api behavior.